# Every derived table must have its own alias mysql error message

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, alias

I have the following query but i'm not sure where the alias is required can anyone assist to prevent the error i'm getting

// error

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

// query

```
SELECT user_id, 
       SUM(win) as won, SUM(draw) As drawn, SUM(loss) as lost, 
       SUM(goals_for) as goals_for, SUM(goals_against) as goals_against, 
       SUM(goals_for) - SUM(goals_against) as goals_difference, 
       player, username, community_result_id, count(*) as played, 
       SUM(points) as points     
FROM 
    ( SELECT home_team_user_id as user_id, 
      CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as win, 
      CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as draw, CASE 
      WHEN home_score < away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as loss,
      CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 3 
  WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END points,
       home_score as goals_for, away_score as goals_against,
       users.name as player, users.username, 
       community_results.community_result_id FROM community_results 
     LEFT JOIN users ON community_results.home_team_user_id=users.id 
     UNION ALL SELECT away_team_user_id as user_id, 
     CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as win, 
     CASE WHEN away_score = home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as draw, 
     CASE WHEN away_score < home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as loss, 
     CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 3 WHEN home_score = away_score 
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END points, away_score as goals_for, home_score as goals_against, 
     users.name as player, users.username, 
     community_results.community_result_id FROM community_results 
     LEFT JOIN users ON community_results.away_team_user_id = users.id ) 
     WHERE user_id = 1 GROUP BY user_id ORDER By won desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: When a query asks for an alias, one solution is to give it one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       SUM(win) as won, SUM(draw) As drawn, SUM(loss) as lost, 
       SUM(goals_for) as goals_for, SUM(goals_against) as goals_against, 
       SUM(goals_for) - SUM(goals_against) as goals_difference, 
       player, username, community_result_id, count(*) as played, 
       SUM(points) as points     
FROM 
    ( SELECT home_team_user_id as user_id, 
      CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as win, 
      CASE WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as draw, CASE 
      WHEN home_score < away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as loss,
      CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 3 
  WHEN home_score = away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END points,
       home_score as goals_for, away_score as goals_against,
       users.name as player, users.username, 
       community_results.community_result_id FROM community_results 
     LEFT JOIN users ON community_results.home_team_user_id=users.id 
     UNION ALL SELECT away_team_user_id as user_id, 
     CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as win, 
     CASE WHEN away_score = home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as draw, 
     CASE WHEN away_score < home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as loss, 
     CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 3 WHEN home_score = away_score 
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END points, away_score as goals_for, home_score as goals_against, 
     users.name as player, users.username, 
     community_results.community_result_id FROM community_results 
     LEFT JOIN users ON community_results.away_team_user_id = users.id ) t
     WHERE user_id = 1 GROUP BY user_id ORDER By won desc LIMIT 1
```